# Same-type constraint 'Element' == 'Array<Element>' is recursive

Tags: arrays, swift, extension-methods

I'd like to make a slick initializer for a matrix that lets me define the row and column count with a default element.  How can create an extension for an Array of Arrays? When I try in the way below,

```
extension Array where Element == Array<SubElement> {

    init(rows: Int, columns: Int, emptyDefault: SubElement) {

        self = [] 
        // implementation
    }

}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
// Same-type constraint 'Element' == 'Array<Element>' is recursive
```

An example usage would be

```
self = [[UIColor]](rows: 20, columns: 30, emptyDefault: .blue)
// This would create a matrix with 20 rows, each row having an array of 30 .blue
```

I want to be able to do something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to create a matrix of elements you can extend `RangeReplaceableCollection` and constrain its elements to `RangeReplaceableCollection` as well. You would need to add default element of type `Element.Element` to your initializer to fill your collections:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: RangeReplaceableCollection { 
    init(rows: Int, columns: Int, element: Element.Element) { 
        self.init(repeating: .init(repeating: element, count: columns), count: rows) 
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let matrix: [[UIColor]] = .init(rows: 3, columns: 3, element: .blue)
```

Comment: Can you include that empty `init()` implementation in the answer too? I was sad to see that deleted.

Comment: You can just to pass the init as the element. The other approach you would need to make the types conform to the protocol

Comment: I'm talking about the one with the `HasInit` protocol...Where it applied to any Element that can be empty initialized without passing any arguments.

Comment: As I said you just need to pass the init as the element `let matrix: [[String]] = .init(rows: 3, columns: 3, element: .init())`

Comment: String has empty init. You provided an implementation in the comments which allowed you do to this `let matrix: [[String]] = .init(rows: 3, columns: 3)` for any Element type that conformed to `hasInit` which was a protocol requiring an empty init function.

Comment: Yes but you would need to make String conform to HasInit `extension String: HasInit {}`

Comment: `protocol HasInit {
    init()
}
extension String: HasInit {}
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: RangeReplaceableCollection,  Element.Element: HasInit {
    init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
        self.init(repeating: .init(repeating: Element.Element(), count: columns), count: rows)
    }

}`

Comment: IMO passing the `init()` is preferred.

Comment: For the first, True. It's still cool.  For the second: Yea! that's the one. For the third: Yes, I agree.

Comment: I could use your help on this one if you're open to it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722764/how-can-i-create-an-operator-to-implement-error-chaining

Answer (score 3):

Leo's answer is good.

But the more constricted solution looks like this, moving the constraint to the initializer:

```swift
extension Array {
  init<Element>(rows: Int, columns: Int, emptyDefault: Element) where Self.Element == [Element] {

  }
}
```

Comment: ooh clever. I like it.

Comment: I liked it too until you made that line too long! `where` clauses generally make lines too wide, so I line up `where` with the keyword that starts whatever it's constricting. Also, I purposefully left off the closing braces. Like this, it won't compile!

Comment: I'm sorry!  I just saw this.  Did you change it back?

Answer (score 0):

Its not perfect, Here my temporary work around:

```
extension Collection where Element: Collection {

}
```

Comment: Good call.   It's weird that Swift permits recursive conformance but not recursive equality.

Comment: @LeoDabus, updated. I want to add methods to generic Array of Arrays which can take a generic element at each cell.

Comment: Its pretty simple, I just want to initialize a matrix with empty cells while defining the number of rows and number of columns.  I can add that.. I don't know how to make it more specific.

Comment: [ [/*row1*/ "cell 1", "cell 2" ],  [/*row2*/ "cell 3", "cell 4" ],  [/*row3*/ "cell 5", "cell 6" ] ]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213828/discussion-between-scottyblades-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: Wow.  Thats cool.  I updated the question too... Let me process what you just commented...

Comment: Wow.  Extremely clever.  Thank you.  If you feel like posting that as an answer, that is exactly what I'm looking for.