# How can I create an operator to implement error chaining?

Tags: swift, error-handling

I want to implement the following operator `»`:

```
throwingFunction(arg: T?)».doStuff()

/*  if throwingFunction throws an error:
     print or log the error
  else 
    returns an object having the doStuff() Method 

OR 

 An Alternative design that I'm open to is 
Instead of a throwing Error, the `throwingFunction()` 
can be swapped out for a method that returns `Result` 

OR
 
a custom Type, with a generic payload type.   
*/
```

Here is an example of something similar to what I'm looking for.  It is a custom implementation of optional chaining made possible using the [KeyPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keypath) object ([credit to Sergey Smagleev](https://medium.com/@sergeysmagleev/how-to-implement-your-own-optional-chaining-in-swift-6cf32e902c3c)
).

```
precedencegroup Chaining {
    associativity: left
}

infix operator ~> : Chaining

extension Optional {
  
  static func ~><T>(value: Wrapped?, key: KeyPath<Wrapped, T> ) -> T? {
    return value.map { $0[keyPath: key] }
  }
  
  static func ~><T>(value: Wrapped?, key: KeyPath<Wrapped, T?> ) -> T? {
    return value.flatMap { $0[keyPath: key] }
  }
  
}

struct Object {
    let anotherOptionalObject: AnotherObject?
}

struct AnotherObject {
    let value: String
}

let optionalObject: Object? = Object(anotherOptionalObject: AnotherObject(value: "Hello world"))

print(optionalObject~>\.anotherOptionalObject~>\.value) //this prints Optional("Hello world")
print(optionalObject?.anotherOptionalObject?.value) //this also prints Optional("Hello world")
```

Except, I want the implementation to provide an opportunity for me to handle the error by printing or logging it.

Comment: If you downvote, can you please provide a reason why? I don't understand why this is getting downvoted, I tried to delete it to satisfy whomever is offended by the question and downvoting it, but StackOverflow isn't letting me.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I think it might be because "Reimagine optional chaining to print or log the cause of being nil" is too unclear a description for what you want to do. Not everyone is like me, who has read your previous question, and thus has more context. You should probably first introduce your `ErrorAlt` type, then say what you want `testMe()».printWin()` to do in the three cases of `ErrorAlt`.

Comment: I still don't think this is possible though because of the same reasons I mentioned in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62711205/how-can-i-implement-a-custom-error-throwing-syntax-in-swift) The closest I managed to get is `(testMe()»)?.printWin()`. By the way, you seem to be reinventing the wheel with your `ErrorAlt` enum - `Result<Success, Failure>` seems to serve the same purpose as it. You could just use `Result<Successm Failure>` here.

Comment: @Sweeper.  For the question feedback.  Thank you.  For the tip in the comment.  Thank you!

Comment: @Sweeper, updated.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Sweeper, I made an implementation below.

Answer (score 2):

`prefix` and `postfix` are *unary* operators i.e. they only accept one operand, whereas an `infix` operator is a *binary* operator i.e. it accepts two operands.

So, `static func »(value:key:) -> Preferred?` is not correct because it's taking two operands whereas you have defined `»` as a `postfix` operator.

Comment: 1. The "'»' is not a postfix unary operator" error is pretty self-explanatory - you're trying to use it as if it was a postfix operator. It's an infix operator, so the LHS has to be a value of type "ErrorAlt<Preferred>" and RHS a value of type "KeyPath<ErrorAlt<Preferred>, T>".

2. The KeyPath error is because its root type is "ErrorAlt<Preferred>" but you're applying it on a value of type "Preferred".

Answer (score -1):

For some reason I get "`»` is not a postfix unary operator" when I don't use the escape syntax.  But apart from that it seems to work.

```
precedencegroup Chaining {
    associativity: left
}

infix operator » : Chaining

extension Result {
    static func »<T>(value: Self, key: KeyPath<Success, T>) -> T? {
        switch value {
        case .success(let win):
            return win[keyPath: key]
        case .failure(let fail):
            print(fail.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }
}

// I included a custom type so that it could be customizable if needed.  
enum Err<Wrapped> {
    static func »<T>(value: Self, key: KeyPath<Wrapped, T>) -> T? {
        switch value {
        case .error(let err):
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        case .some(let wrapper):
            return wrapper[keyPath: key]
        }
    }
    case error(Error)
    case some(Wrapped)
}

func errorWrapped() -> Err<String> {
    .some("Hello World")
}

func pleaseWork()  {
    print(errorWrapped()»\.isEmpty)
}
```

Comment: You seem to have discovered that key paths don't work with methods like you originally thought.

Comment: @Sweeper, are you referring to the slash? Or the non-throwing methods? Cause yes those were difficult.  I tried to expand the question definition scope to not restrict it to throwing methods.  And yea.. It's still not all the way there.  It keeps requiring a slash.

Comment: @Sweeper, yea. It's not working as expected when the right side accepts a closure as an argument.